# Grammar problem in close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog

Our "off topic" close reason has a problem:

[image]

It should read either "generally relate to **a** code review request" or "generally relate to code review **requests**." Can we get it fixed before anyone from [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com) visits us?

*Let's see here...image, freehand circles, let's hope no one misses the ponies...*

Comment: btw, it's spelled 'grammar' :P

Comment: Isn't that ironic.

Comment: "Can we get *it* fixed..." :P